# i'm trying to build CNN with the one dimensional mnist dataset. i got stucked at reshapig the dateset

Tags: conv-neural-network, reshape, mnist

```
history = model.fit(train_datagen.flow(x_train.reshape(60000, 28, 28, 1), keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train), batch_size=32),
 epochs=20, validation_data=(x_test, keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)))
```

I keep getting this error below
please help

```
Epoch 1/20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

----> 8 history = model.fit(train_datagen.flow(x_train.reshape(60000, 28, 28, 1), keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train), batch_size=32),
      9  epochs=20, validation_data=(x_test, keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)))
```

I tried to reshape and train the dataset

Answer (score 0):

```
history = model.fit(train_datagen.flow(x_train.reshape(-1, 28, 28), keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train), batch_size=32), epochs=20, validation_data=(x_test.reshape(-1, 28, 28), keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)))
```

In the modified code, reshape(-1, 28, 28) is used to reshape the x_train and x_test datasets. The -1 in the reshape function is a placeholder that automatically calculates the appropriate size for the first dimension based on the provided shape. This ensures that the number of samples is maintained while reshaping the data to a 3D format.

With this modification, the CNN model should be able to take the reshaped MNIST data as input without encountering the shape mismatch error